# Symfony 2 Form not saving data from select (on joined table)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have created a form that appears to be correct, it has a few text fields and a select box with a list of countries pulled from a table of countries I have. The select box displays correctly using the the correct values for it's 'value' and display text. When I submit the form however I get an exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'countryid' cannot be null
```

If I set the database table (in PHPMyAdmin) to allow a null value for the countryid field it enters the record with no exception but the entry for the countryid is null.

my controller has the following code:

```
        $duck = new \Wfuk\DuckBundle\Entity\Ducks();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($duck)
       ->add('city', 'text')
       ->add('countryid', 'entity', array('class' => 'WfukDuckBundle:Country', 'property' => 'country'))
       // cut other fields
       ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate( $form );

    echo $duck->getCountryid();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($duck);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('upload_duck_success'));
        }
```

the echo in there returns the __toString function of the country object which seems a bit odd - but it is the full country info for the country chosen in the form.

in the Ducks.php class:

```
 /**
 * @var string $countryid
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="countryid", type="string", length=2, nullable=false)
 */
private $countryid;

/**
 * Set countryid
 *
 * @param string $countryId
 */
public function setCountryid($countryid)
{
    $this->countryid = $countryid;
}

/**
 * Get countryid
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountryid()
{
    return $this->countryid;
}
```

This is my first symfony project, but I've been over the docs several times and think I have everything set up ok...

edit:

I have a join set up as follows:
Ducks.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="ducks")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="countryid", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $country;

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}
```

and on the Country.php side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ducks", mappedBy="country")
 */
protected $ducks;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ducks = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get ducks
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getDucks()
{
    return $this->ducks;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that the form is sending an actual Country object to ducks.  You can confirm this with:

```
public function setCountryid($countryid)
{
    if (is_object($countryid)) die('Yep, got a country object.');
    $this->countryid = $countryid;
}
```

It sounds like you only want to store a 2 char country code?  You don't want an actual relation?  If so then this might do the trick:

```
public function setCountryid($countryid)
{
    if (is_object($countryid)) $countryid = $countryid->getId();
    $this->countryid = $countryid;
}
```

If you want an actual normal Doctrine managed relation between duck and country then something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 */
private $country;
```

And adjust your getter/setters accordingly.

It's a bit strange that you seem to have both yml and annotations.  From what I understood, you could use one or the other in a given bundle.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. You're right about it being an object and your code to turn it to the two character country code worked in as much as my echo just echoed the code rather than the complete country object, however I still get the same error that 'countryid cannot be null' I've added my join code to the original question as that may be at fault. Ideally I want to use a doctrine managed relation. I've also removed the ducks.orm.yml file in case that was confusing the issue.

Comment: Ok.  First step is to read through the Doctrine manual on associations:  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html.  Since you are dealing with objects, get rid of all this 'countryid' stuff.  Then start with a one way ManyToOne relation from duck to country.  Get that working then add in the county to duck relation if you really need it.  If you still have trouble then delete most of your original question and just post your updated ducks/country code.  You might also consider adding a Symfony 2 command and testing from the command line.

Comment: You're right the whole country_id thing was unnecessary, I removed that and changed a few lines of code and it all worked perfectly. I really appreciate the help - thanks.